# Grouping js files returns a strange js error

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, google-closure-compiler

I have a website, which uses different javascript plugins, and a bunch of js files to run (~30). I wanted to try to group these js files into a single file, and tried to apply a basic minification to it(only removing whitespaces) using **Google's Closure Compiler**.

I've introduced all of the js files, in the same order as they are included in my page to the Closure Compilers online version, and run the compilation. The parameters for the compilation looked like this:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @output_file_name default.js
// @compilation_level WHITESPACE_ONLY
// .... bunch of javascript files here
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

The compilation ran with success, there were neither warnings nor errors. I then fetched the result file, copied it to my server, and tried to include it to my page.

The page runs, but a strange error appears, which stops my javascript in the middle of it's operation:

```
TypeError: event.feature.values_ is undefined
```

I've tried to fetch the space where this error is happening, the code there looks something like this:

```
this.vectorLayer.getSource().on("addfeature",function(event){if(typeof event.feature.values_.type=="undefined")return;
```

This is something which my own javascript code is doing, but this part of the code shouldn't even run when the page is loading. When I use the separate javascript files, the page loads just greatly, without any errors, but with the white-space removed, and the files combined, this error appears.

With basic logic, I tought that by adding together the `.js` files in the same order in which they are included on my page, and only removing the white-spaces to get a smaller file size shouldn't result in any errors, as the browser loads the js files in synchronously anyways. Am I mistaken in this regard? If not, what could the possible reason for this error be?

**EDIT 1:**

Okay, so I narrowed down the problem to a single `.js` file, the javascript file of `OpenLayers`. If I do not compile that file, and include it separatly, everything works fine. What could be causing this strange problem?

Comment: Even removing whitespace from a file can break JavaScript. For instance, if it uses the `toString()` method of a function for reflection that can easily break by removing whitespace.

Comment: Why do you rely on `event.feature.values_`? Why don't you use an API method?

Comment: @JonatasWalker could you elaborate? What API method?

Comment: Well, I can't find `event.feature.values_` in OL files so I suppose this is in your own files, am I wrong?

Comment: @JonatasWalker yes, the error is coming from my own file. I've tried to debug the problem, and when I am using the non-grouped js files, that specific functions always has an `event.feature` with a `values_` property, yet if I manually add a `console.log` to the grouped js file, the `event.feature` variable is filled with strange, minified looking properties like `Ra`, `Ba`, and `ya`.

Comment: That's why I'm telling you to use an API method instead of relying on an internal object. Use something like `event.feature.getKeys()` or `event.feature.getProperties()`.

Comment: I'm guessing based on this discussion you aren't using the same JS source files - because renaming like you are listing doesn't occur with closure-compiler's `WHITESPACE_ONLY` level. Are you using the min.js files with closure-compiler and original files when testing it manually?

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth Basically I found the problem, but it's still a strange one. Firstly, I've indeed used the minified version of openlayers with the Closure Compiler, but later on I've changed it. Yet Google somehow, cached the minified version, and was still using that file over the non-minified one. Restarting the Closure Compiler, and reintroducing all the js files again, solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this was caused by a strange caching mechanism on Google's side. Restarting the **Closure Compiler**, and reintroducing all the js files once again, then recompiling it, solved my problem.

Thanks for the comments guys!

Comment: You should accept your own answer. This is a definite problem with the online version.

Comment: And maybe file a bug report at https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/issues/ especially since you spent so much time figuring out a test case